# Is there any Lore explanation as to why multiples of a character may exist?

Tags: apex-legends

Apex has a bunch of lore behind it, but did they ever touch on why there could be 10 Lifelines that drop?

Like that person is a defined character and all of a sudden she's got a bunch of clones?

As apex has a bunch of lore, it seems weird that they would just gloss over that.

Answer (score -1):

This might be a bit late, but the gameplay does not equal the lore. While in gameplay multiples of a character may exist, in the lore, only one of each legend exists. The remaining players are random mercenaries trying to make a name for themselves like the legends have.